# Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPSolutionPipeBind'

Tags: sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012

Getting this error when i try to deploy a .wsp to a SharePoint 2013 portal. Someone have any idea?

*Get-SPSolution : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPSolutionPipeBind' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\360Install\Version 4.1 SP6\Setup\Data\Scripts\SharePoint2010\Common\SIMapping.psm1:229 char:37
+     $existingSolution = Get-SPSolution $SolutionId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-SPSolution], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetSolution*

Comment: You need to paste your PowerShell script. It's not possible to figure out the cause with only the error message.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually comes up when a collection is supplied to the parameter, which is actually expecting an object. For a better understanding i have provided an example below:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty  -SearchApplication $ssa -Category 'Business Data' | Where {$_.Name -Match "GetProduct"} | ft Name
```

The above example will throw the same error you encountered. Now in the above case there are more than 1 search service application installed on the server. So the first line of code returns a collection rather than a single object. In the second line, you can notice that the collection is being assigned to the property **Search Application**, which is expecting a single object.